# Articles before nouns and "or" conjunction

Tags: syntactic-analysis, articles, conjunctions, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I am trying to understand the correct use of articles before nouns that are separated by "or". For example.

> It doesn't matter whether you are a mobile or a frontend developer
>   ....

Or it should be

> It doesn't matter whether you are a mobile or frontend developer
>   ....

Could you explain rules that should be used in such cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Style may determine--you need as much repetition as necessary to avoid confusing the reader.

Comment: @Xanne , thanks for answer, what would you choose ?

Comment: I'd include the article both times.